# Backbone - partial fetch on model

Tags: backbone.js

I believe it's now possible to save only part of a client model to the server, but is it possible to fetch only a part of it?

Is there anything better than:

```
var sectionName = "overview";
model.fetch({ data: $.param({ section: sectionName}) });
```

I'd ideally rather declare the specific attribute of the model I want updating.

Comment: Partial save is now done via the `patch` method (where there is browser support), but there is no direct analogue for fetch.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no backbone specific way to do exactly what you want exactly as you describe it, but if your model has group-able properties like:

```
bobTheUser = {
    posts: [
        {
            id:1,
            content: "This is Bob's first post!"
        }, {
            id:2,
            content: "Wow! Another stunner!"
        }
    ],
    friendIds: [1729, 3301],
    salesforce: {oh: "no! SOAP!!!"}
}
```

You can pass `fetch` optional parameters to let your api know that you just want Bob's `posts` and `friendIds`, but not his `salesforce` information.

I think this type of solution is about as close as you'll get to what you asked for, but I've been wrong before!

Comment: Thanks! I don't suppose you'd have some example code for overriding fetch? It's not something I've ever done before.

Comment: You actually don't need to override fetch for the above to work. Just pass the `data` param to fetch as you did in your original post.